# How to have my google oauth only try and authorize the app on a certain route

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra

I have a google Oauth that will make the user authorize when a user goes to my webpage, however I only want them to have to authorize the app so that I can get their access and refresh tokens when they go to certain  page to enter a google api information.Google is making them authorize no matter what route they are on any ideas on how to stop this.Ruby wont let me any of this in a route.

```
def user_credentials
# Build a per-request oauth credential based on token stored in 
session
# which allows us to use a shared API client.
@authorization ||= (
auth = settings.authorization.dup
auth.redirect_uri = to('/oauth2callback')
auth.update_token!(session)
auth
)
end

configure do

 Google::Apis::ClientOptions.default.application_name = 'Get Login 
 info for Google Ad Exchange'
 Google::Apis::ClientOptions.default.application_version = '1.0.0'

 client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
 authorization = client_secrets.to_authorization
 authorization.scope = 
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller.readonly'

  set :authorization, authorization
end

before do
# Ensure user has authorized the app
unless user_credentials.access_token || request.path_info =~ 
/^\/oauth2/
redirect to('/oauth2authorize')
end
end


 after do
 # Serialize the access/refresh token to the session and credential 
 store.
# We could potentially need to pull back the client_id and 
client_secret as well and add them to the dynamo database.

#   session[:client_id] = user_credentials.client_id
#   session[:client_secret] = user_credentials.client_secret
    session[:access_token] = user_credentials.access_token
    session[:refresh_token] = user_credentials.refresh_token
    session[:expires_in] = user_credentials.expires_in
    session[:issued_at] = user_credentials.issued_at

  end

get '/oauth2authorize' do
 # Request authorization
 redirect user_credentials.authorization_uri.to_s, 303
 end

get '/oauth2callback' do
 # Exchange token
 user_credentials.code = params[:code] if params[:code]
 user_credentials.fetch_access_token!
 redirect to('/')

  end
```

Comment: Please indent your code per the Ruby coding guidelines. It helps us help you. You have lines that wrapped and are syntax errors. I'd recommend fixing those as they're cause for closing questions. "[mcve]" and the linked pages help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, meant to post way earlier but had an alert on this post so i figured id update to what we did to ake it work.

```
 get '/googleauth' do
   salesforce_username = params[:salesforce_username] || ''
   unless session.has_key?(:credentials)
   redirect to('/oauth2callback')
 end
   client_opts = JSON.parse(session[:credentials])
   auth_client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_opts)
   redirect to('/googleadx')
 end

 get '/oauth2callback' do
  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
  auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
  auth_client.update!(
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller.readonly',
:redirect_uri => url('/oauth2callback'))
 if request['code'] == nil
  auth_uri = auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s
  redirect to(auth_uri)
 else
  auth_client.code = request['code']
  auth_client.fetch_access_token!
  session[:access_token] = auth_client.access_token
  session[:refresh_token] = auth_client.refresh_token
  session[:expires_in] = auth_client.expires_in
  session[:issued_at] = auth_client.issued_at
  auth_client.client_secret = nil
  session[:credentials] = auth_client.to_json
  redirect to('/googleadx')
end
end

get '/googleadx' do

# configure()

if params[:username]
    successmessage = params[:username] + "'s credentials added successfully."
else
    message = ''
end

salesforce_username = session[:salesforce_username] || ''
access_token = session[:access_token]
refresh_token = session[:refresh_token]
googleDollarLimit = ''

erb :googleadx, locals: {message: message, successmessage: successmessage, salesforce_username: salesforce_username, access_token: access_token, refresh_token: refresh_token, googleDollarLimit: googleDollarLimit}
end
```